# Unable to run war file on wildfly running Amazon EC2 windows instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, wildfly

I am working on Spring Boot and my API is working fine when I test it on the local Windows system on the Wildfly server but when I deploy the same war file on the Wildfly server running on Amazon EC2 Windows instance then it shows **404 - Not Found**.

**Measures taken by me:**
modified the standalone.xml file.

```
<interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
```

and ***running the wildfly with -b 0.0.0.0*** but still its showing **404 - Not Found**.
but I am able to acess the localhost:8080 and localhost:9990  but when I hit localhost:8080/war_file_name/employees it always shows **404 - Not Found**

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, earlier I was deploying the war file using the management console, and this time I deployed the war file directly inside the standalone->deployment folder and it worked.

***I have no explanation for this.***